# Schedule 40 or schedule 80 PVC where feeder wire comes out of ground?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, conduit

Our well pump installer is still using schedule 40 for running pump wires up to exposed well head. I checked with a contractor and they still use schedule 40 outside buildings, but EMT inside. I'm guessing this means our county is still using older codes??? (I've emailed and called building dept, but no answer.) Should I use schedule 80 and an expansion joint for my run of feeders coming out of ground to supply the pump house? What would be a good choice for exposed conduit to run feeders along interior wall to the surface mount panel? I'm running #2 Al XHHW conductors (and #6 EGC) up through slab, approximately 6-8' along wall to reach the panel.

Comment: I don't think Sched 40 vs 80 is going to make or break your project. The primary difference between the two is the wall thickness - and therefore durability. For residential, 40 is probably sub-adequate depending on the ground where you live. Its very possible your locality doesn't require 80 for residential.
I would personally use schedule 40 or 80 anywhere rigid steel isn't an option.

Comment: Primary problem is that most of the length of the stub-up is taken up by the expansion joint itself, which isn't as durable as Sch80...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  I didn't realize that. So, maybe I should skip the expansion fitting. I thought I read they should be installed above expected snow levels anyway. But the way things are going that might require a flag pole :/.